# E-Bike Battery not working

Tags: electric-bike, battery, charging

I have borrowed an e-bike from a friend few days ago. Yesterday battery was empty so I left it to charge last night. I left it overnight. Now when I put it in bike it does not work, not responding.
I try to put in charger again but not responding, non of the lights are blinking anymore.

I used the bike's original charger. Charger itself does not have lights that indicates if is it charging or not.

There is a button for turning the battery on and off but seems like it is not working.
But when I press it for a longer period the place around the stop button begins to heat.

Battery type is : powerpack 500 BOSCH (Li-ion 500Wh Made in Hungary)

Has anyone had a similar experience?
What should I do?

Comment: Disappear and live out your days in a cabin in the woods before your friend finds out.  (humour)

Comment: On the side of the 500 power pack it should have a battery indicator press the button and see if the lights light up ? If they indicate there is a charge, look for a manual online to see if there’s a specific way to start up.

Comment: @DanK Lights does not turn on after i press the the button on battery. But the battery is warm around the button even 2 days has passed after the charge.

Comment: Does the wall voltage/frequency in your location differ from your friend's electricity?   Do you run on a generator?

Comment: @Criggie no it is the same. Thank you for reply. I have taken the bike to the nearest shop. They will check if the battery can be repaired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tell your friend ASAP that the bike is not charging.  Ask if there is a trick to making it work.

Your worst case is the battery has died, and you need to offer to contribute toward a new one.  When borrowing something, you are responsible for it, and and for any damage.

Your friend might have known the battery was on its last-legs, if they didn't tell you, that's not very friendly.  However that interaction would be more on-topic at https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

E-Bike was just 1 and a half year old
The e-bike battery from bosch has 2 years warranty.
The e-bike itself has just 1 year warranty.
Battery was sent from a local store to bosch and I received a new one!